# Meaning of "claim" in "Her choices have been narrowed by a loss of faith among Germany’s elite in the claim"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In an article of `The Economist`:

> Germany’s chancellor, Angela Merkel, is said to be wrestling with how to position her country in an age of sharp competition between two self-interested giants, America and China.
>
> Her choices have been narrowed by a loss of faith among Germany’s elite **in the claim**, once touted as “change through trade”, that com- merce with China will nudge that country towards openness and democracy.

What does "**in the claim**" mean here?

Answer (score 1):

The claim is "commerce with China will nudge that country [China] toward openness and democracy".

When the writer says people are losing faith in the claim, it means they no longer accept it as prima facie true, either because they now believe it is actually false, or at least they suspect it might be false and want further evidence.